# Judging quality of drywall workmanship

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, mudding

I am a new home owner. I recently had water damage to my house and needed to have the drywall in my ceilings stripped and replaced (first floor and basement). My contractor has completed the work but I found some issues. I am not sure if these are serious or not, or if I am just being picky. I was wondering if I could get some advice.

1. First, where the contractor butted the new drywall ceiling against the original section, that was not damaged, there is a change in gradient and the drywall is not level. This is more apparent along the wall/ceiling joint and you can see that it is not a straight line.
2. Along the wall, where the ceiling drywall joins the wall, there are large gaps. They have already finished mudding and painting, so I think they intend to just cover these large gaps with molding. Should these gaps be taped and mudded as well?
3. I have recessed lighting. Some of the holes that were cut out were cut too large. When I placed the lights, which have about a 1/4 flange, over the cut out hole, I can see the flange will not cover the entire hole. As I mentioned, the ceiling has already been taped, mudded, and painted, so I don't expect they will be doing any more work. I am not sure how they expect to fix this?

I would ask the contractor, but they've been difficult to get in contact with and have not been showing up the past few days. I get the feeling I will be told it's all normal, which is why I wanted to check here first.

Thanks

**Edit - Photos**

Here are some photos.  The first two are what it looks like all around the wall in my kitchen, with the gaps.

[image]
[image]

This is what the lights look like:

[image]

And this is the basement.  The first photo you can see a bend in the ceiling.  The next photo I use a level to demonstrate the slope.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks pretty bad to me. For example, the ceiling-wall gaps *could* be covered with molding, but it would have to be fairly large as the gaps look a bit bigger than normal. I'll let one of the experts answer in more detail - with the pictures I'm sure somebody will have something to say.

Comment: Thanks @manassehkatz. Yes, any advice I can get from the experts would be greatly appreciated. I've never had to deal with this before and I'm a bit lost and worried.

Comment: Is there crown going up in the kitchen? That would cover the gap and account for the lack of taping in the corners. Regarding the lights, that's slightly sloppy but easy to fix with a bit more mud/tape/dry time/paint. The basement hump is also fix-able, but will require a long skim on either side of the bump. (Again, sloppy in my opinion, but sometimes basements don't get the respect other parts of the house do, and your contract might not clearly spell out how flat the old/new should be.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, crown molding will go up. But, should I ask to have the gaps taped and mudded? Or just covered up? I feel like just covering it up is sloppy work. But, maybe that's a standard practice?

Comment: Regarding the kitchen specifically, I would tape the corners. I'd liken it to fire-taping a garage. (But I can't actually quote chapter and verse of code that supports that opinion.)

Comment: This all looks horrible; the light is probably the easiest fix. But those gaps and the bulge in the basement are unacceptable. I don't care if it is getting crown; you should hang it as if it isn't regardless. That bulge isn't featherable...